# How to write test class for contact detail page

Tags: visualforce, unit-test

My controller:

```
public class contactdetailpage {
  public contact con{set;get;}
        public list<ContactActivities__c> ca1{get;set;}
    public string conid{set;get;}
    public contactdetailpage(apexpages.StandardController std)
    {
      ca1=new list<ContactActivities__c>();
       conid=apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');             


        con=[select id,lastname,Email,phone,Leadsource from contact where id=:conid];
        system.debug('---conid---'+conid);
          ca1=[select name,Activity_Type__c,AppointmentDate__c,Status__c,Any_Remarks__c from ContactActivities__c where Remarks__c=:con.Id];
        System.debug('The contact acivity list is'+ca1);
    }   

    public pageReference newAcivityMtd()
    {

     pageReference pg=new pageReference('/apex/PopupVF2');
        pg.getParameters().put('contactID',conid);
        return pg;
    }
}
```

My VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="contactdetailpage" >
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(funtion(){
                          $("[value='new ContactActivity']").attr('onclick','');
                              })                                      
                               $(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
                                   $('.popupBackground').show();
                                   })

                                $(document).on('change','.status',function(){

        var sts=$('.status').val();

                  if(sts=='Cancelled')
        {

            $('.mat').show();
            }
        else
            $('.mat').hide();
    });
        </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .popupBackground{
        background-color:black;
        opacity: 0.20;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9998; 
    }
    .custPopup{
        background-color: white;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 50%;
        padding:10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: -250px;
        top:100px;
    }


    .ema1
        {
      border: 1px solid red;
        }
        .ema2
        {
      border: 1px solid grey;
        }


</style>
    <apex:form >
     <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageBlockSection >
             <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.lastname}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.email}"/>
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.phone}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Leadsource}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock> 

        </apex:form>
    <apex:relatedList list="Activities__r" subject="{!Contact}" title="Contact Activity"/>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: You are not using the extension class variables anywhere in your VF page then why do you need that? I think you can get rid of that extension and can deploy things without any test class.

Comment: Have you tried completing this trailhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet could be a good start on writing test classes.

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.YourVisualforcePageName;

//create a Contact record 
Account acct = new Account(name = 'test1');
insert acct;

Contact con = new Contact (LastName = 'test Last Name', AccountId = acct.Id);
insert con;

//put contact Id as parameters
pageRef.getParameters().put('id',con.Id);

Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

//create instance of StandardController
ApexPages.StandardController std = new Apexpages.StandardController(con);

//create an instance of your Controller
contactdetailpage  controller = new contactdetailpage (std);
```